# Sorlbridge/Solr is very slow for 300k products

Tags: magento, solr

I installed solrbridge on my website and I have a problem with performance. Everything was ok for 10k products. but after upload 320k product request to solr takes 55-70s. I noticed this happens only for the first request.

for example this url:
[sample_local_url](http://localhost:8983/solr/english/select/?q=**&spellcheck.q=&facet.field=category_path&facet.field=PLN_0_price_decimal&facet.field=category_url_facet&facet.range=PLN_0_price_decimal&f.PLN_0_price_decimal.facet.range.start=0&f.PLN_0_price_decimal.facet.range.end=100000&f.PLN_0_price_decimal.facet.range.gap=10000&f.PLN_0_price_decimal.facet.mincount=1&fq=(store_id:%221%22)%20AND%20(website_id:%221%22)%20AND%20(product_status:%221%22)%20AND%20(category_id:%2216%22%20OR%20category_id:%2216%22%20OR%20category_id:%2221%22%20OR%20category_id:%2250%22%20OR%20category_id:%22256%22%20OR%20category_id:%22257%22%20OR%20category_id:%22258%22%20OR%20category_id:%2251%22%20OR%20category_id:%22259%22%20OR%20category_id:%22260%22%20OR%20category_id:%2222%22%20OR%20category_id:%2252%22%20OR%20category_id:%2253%22%20OR%20category_id:%2254%22%20OR%20category_id:%2255%22%20OR%20category_id:%2256%22%20OR%20category_id:%2257%22%20OR%20category_id:%2223%22%20OR%20category_id:%2258%22%20OR%20category_id:%22261%22%20OR%20category_id:%22262%22%20OR%20category_id:%22263%22%20OR%20category_id:%2259%22%20OR%20category_id:%22264%22%20OR%20category_id:%22265%22%20OR%20category_id:%22266%22%20OR%20category_id:%2224%22%20OR%20category_id:%2260%22%20OR%20category_id:%2261%22%20OR%20category_id:%2262%22%20OR%20category_id:%2263%22%20OR%20category_id:%2264%22%20OR%20category_id:%22267%22%20OR%20category_id:%22268%22%20OR%20category_id:%22269%22%20OR%20category_id:%2265%22%20OR%20category_id:%2266%22%20OR%20category_id:%22270%22%20OR%20category_id:%22271%22%20OR%20category_id:%22272%22%20OR%20category_id:%2267%22%20OR%20category_id:%22273%22%20OR%20category_id:%22274%22%20OR%20category_id:%22275%22%20OR%20category_id:%2268%22%20OR%20category_id:%2269%22%20OR%20category_id:%22276%22%20OR%20category_id:%22277%22%20OR%20category_id:%22278%22%20OR%20category_id:%2270%22%20OR%20category_id:%22279%22%20OR%20category_id:%22280%22%20OR%20category_id:%2271%22%20OR%20category_id:%2272%22%20OR%20category_id:%22281%22%20OR%20category_id:%22282%22%20OR%20category_id:%2273%22%20OR%20category_id:%22283%22%20OR%20category_id:%22284%22%20OR%20category_id:%2274%22%20OR%20category_id:%22285%22%20OR%20category_id:%22286%22%20OR%20category_id:%2275%22%20OR%20category_id:%22287%22%20OR%20category_id:%22288%22%20OR%20category_id:%22289%22%20OR%20category_id:%2276%22%20OR%20category_id:%22290%22%20OR%20category_id:%22291%22%20OR%20category_id:%22292%22%20OR%20category_id:%2277%22%20OR%20category_id:%22293%22%20OR%20category_id:%22294%22%20OR%20category_id:%22295%22%20OR%20category_id:%2225%22%20OR%20category_id:%2278%22%20OR%20category_id:%2279%22%20OR%20category_id:%2280%22%20OR%20category_id:%2281%22%20OR%20category_id:%2282%22%20OR%20category_id:%2226%22%20OR%20category_id:%2283%22%20OR%20category_id:%2284%22%20OR%20category_id:%2285%22)%20AND%20(filter_visibility_int:%222%22%20OR%20filter_visibility_int:%224%22)&stats.field=PLN_0_price_decimal&stats.field=sort_PLN_0_special_price_decimal&sort=sort_cat_16_pos_int%20asc) (now working, please inspect to check params)

takes **56[s]** for the first time, and after it takes **50-60[ms]** (even in different web browser so this cannot be local web browser cache)

And this is happening with all requests. I understand there is some kind of cache in solr. I wonder if this is possible to increase the performance of this.

Comment: Have you tried adding a few decent warming queries? These are used to populate the cache when starting from a cold state. Solr also includes the time a query took in its logs, so you can confirm that its the query that's slow and not the handling of it. In regard to your sample URL - have you tried removing calls to some of the module to try to debug where the issue could be? Using the stats module might be slow, the facets you're using might be hard to generate the first time, and you have a lot of ORs (which I think would be OK, but it doesn't hurt to actually experiment and test it out)

Comment: Hello,  thanks for the response. It turned out there was a weird q phrase in solrbridge extension.  Have no idea why but they use ** as phrase.  I have no idea why,  but I changed it to * an everything speed up.  I red somewhere that this phrase was used as ground search in older solrbridge versions but didn't found in current documentation. Anyway, thanks for the response. Thanks to you I added warming up option as well